# Filter the date column of database in c# with linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have a Table with 3 Columns, Id, Name and Birthday

```
Id | Name | Birthday
-- | ---- | -----------
1  | John | 1993/07/12
2  | Sarah| 1995/02/05
3  | Jack | 1990/10/01
```

Now i going to show `Person` in `DataGridView` that their `Birthday` is Lower then 1994/05/20
I using LINQ to create Query

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Please share me the code you have written?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your **`Birthday`** column is of type **`Date`**

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact("1994/05/20", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result =   from t in context.table
               where t.Birthday < dt
               select t;
```

**`EDIT`**

If its of type string, you need to convert to Date format and compare as above

```
 var result =   from t in context.table
                   where   DateTime.Parse(t.Birthday,"yyyy/MM/dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < dt
                   select t;
```

Comment: This won't work since Birthday is nText.

Comment: The question says `The type of Birthday Column is nText not Date`

Comment: What's the point of **assuming** something which OP clearly stated is not their case?

Comment: may be i am color blind , did not read the question clearly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, give me this error, The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: You're missing a "using namespace System.Globalization;"

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, thanks

Comment: mark as answer if this helped

Answer (score 1):

Going with the assumption that Birthday is always in a YYYY/MM/DD format, then:

```
Persons.Where(p=>p.Birthday<"1994/05/20");
```

But this only works because dates in YYYY/MM/DD are sortable, so you don't need to parse them out to a real date/datetime object and comparing them as string actually still works.

If the LINQ provider you are using doesn't support string compares using <, then you can do this instead:

```
Persons.Where(p=>p.Birthday.CompareTo("1994/05/20") < 0);
```

Comment: True, but unfortunately there is no `<`  operator for `string`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, I keep forgetting most don't, so I've added a workaround.

Comment: I meant C# :) Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Most of the Answer posted here assume Birthday as DateTime column.**

First we'll have to *parse text to DateTime* and then compare as shown below

Try this :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("1994/20/05");

var result = EmployeeDetails.Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.Birthday ,"yyyy/dd/mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < dt ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, give me this error, The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: use using System.Globalization. It is good to use CultureInfo as your application may have the provision of different culture settings

Comment: may be now you can upvote and accept it as answer

Comment: give me this error : `Method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using dates do yourself a favor and use a [strongly typed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ea38b96-921c-4218-8c28-168f33b4bf62/-what-does-strongly-typed-xxx-mean-?forum=csharplanguage) fields,
it will save you a lot of "headaches" in the future.

in the example you can see that a new strongly typed DataColumn field is declared and all the strings that contains dates are converted into a "real" date. then use LINQ to filter your results safely to a new data structure (in the example i choose `DataTable`).

```
private void Funky()
{
    DataColumn RealDate = new DataColumn("RealDate");
    RealDate.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
    dt.Columns.Add(RealDate);

    // strongly type a DateTime Column it will save you alot of problems in the future
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] temp = dt.Rows[i]["BirthDay"].ToString().Split('/');
        dt.Rows[i]["RealDate"] = new DateTime(int.Parse(temp[0]), int.Parse(temp[1]), int.Parse(temp[2]));
    }

    // finaly get you result
    var targetDate = new DateTime(20, 5, 1994);

    DataTable FilterDt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("RealDate") < targetDate).Select(y => y).CopyToDataTable();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = FilterDt;
}
```

Comment: what is `dt` and `RealDate` ?